# How to get a user's IP address in an OpenAM server-side script

Tags: javascript, openam

I'm writing a server side script for the OpenAM platform. I need to be able to get the user's IP address, either with javascript or Groovy (java). I can see that it's a value that's being captured in the system, but I can't figure out how to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

While using JQuery a javascript libary you can get the ip from another site like

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://geoip.nekudo.com/api/",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(response) {
    $('.some-selector').html(response.ip)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the data I needed:

In the OpenAM Script module (javascript):

```
requestData.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
```

This will get you a comma-separated string of the IP addresses that the request has gone through, with the original being the first in the string. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For